# How to type the actual German quotation marks?

Tags: support

How can one produce the right German quotation marks? I've been opening them with a *double comma*, and closing with a normal upper-quotation mark.

*,,Like this"*

The space between this ad hoc solution is not the desired one, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + 0132 = „
<kbd>ALT</kbd> + 0147 = “
<kbd>ALT</kbd> + 0148 = ”

For Linux (Ubuntu at least), with the keyboard in German,

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> = „
<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> = “

And for *Guillemets*

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> = »
<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> = «

Comment: Sorry, das funktioniert nicht für Linux (vll. in Windows schon)

Comment: @c.p. Selbst Schuld ;) Versuch mal [Compose] [,] ["] & [Compose] [<] ["] & [Compose] [>] ["] -  Ich kann das nicht testen, weil ich kein Unixsystem verwende. Wenn's aber passt, ergänze ich die Antwort.

Comment: hab ich selbst hinzugefügt, was für mich funktioniert hat.

Comment: @c.p.: You can view and modify the keymap with `xmodmap`.